# Magento - Editing Customer Information then saving causes error

Tags: magento

In Magento, under Customers, when you edit a Customer, from the smallest change or even no change, and then click save, I get the following error in the debug console:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() 
must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of 
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in 
/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Form.php on line 327 and defined  in 
/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59
```

After that, the Please Wait message hangs forever and nothing is updated, even if I refresh or go back.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was able to fix my problem. It was caused by the Amasty Customer Attribute extension since I updated my database recently. I disabled it and the problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error:

Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given

Viewing the page source, I saw the page stopped just before outputting the customers gender.  I found that eav_attribute.attribute_model had been updated with 'eav/entity_attribute' for the 'gender' attribute_code.

Temporary fix:
UPDATE eav_attribute SET attribute_model='' WHERE attribute_code='gender';

Then the broken pages work fine again.. until something happens and the value is updated with 'eav/entity_attribute' again...

Background:
I did create my own attribute with the same attribute_code 'gender' (- what a mistake), but have since deleted my attribute but the problem persists intermittently throughout the day.  I believe it's after each new order or after saving some object.

Conclusion:
I believe the problem happens from creating a new attribute with an existing attribute_code.  Delete & re-create the new attribute with a new attribute_code.  Stop the eav_attribute.attribute_model field getting updated somehow!

Good luck